android.os.BadParcelableException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = java.util.LinkedHashSet)
I have created a share function inside a (@Composable using Jetpack Compose, latests versions of all the gradle and lib.versions.toml with Android Studio Jellyfish)
     that call Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)

the intent send without problem my file but the issue crash my app.
All my class and object implements Parcelable and Serialized, the problem is that I can not find  the LinkedHashSet that cause the issue.
Gemini can not help me and I tried to isolate the issue without result
    fun createKmlFile(context: Context, kml: String, trailName: String): File? {
        try {
            // crea la directory kml_files nella cache dell'app se non esiste già,
            //  e poi salva il file trail.kml all'interno di quella directory
            val cacheDir = context.cacheDir
            val kmlDirectory = File(cacheDir, "kml_files")

            // Crea la directory se non esiste
            if (!kmlDirectory.exists()) {
                kmlDirectory.mkdirs()
            }
            val file = File(kmlDirectory, "$trailName.kml")
            val fileWriter = FileWriter(file)
            fileWriter.write(kml)
            fileWriter.close()
            return file
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("Vagabondo", "Error creating KML file", e)
            return null
        }
    }

    fun shareTrail(kml: String, trailName: String, context: Context) {
        val kmlFile = createKmlFile(context, kml, trailName)
        if (kmlFile != null) {
            val kmlUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                context,
                "${context.packageName}.fileprovider",
                kmlFile
            )
            Log.d("Vagabondo", "created kml uri: $kmlUri")
            val sendIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND).apply {
                type = "application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml"
                addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
                addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                putExtra(EXTRA_STREAM, kmlUri)
            }
            launcher.launch(sendIntent)
        }
    }

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    
Process: net.xxx, PID: 21214
android.os.BadParcelableException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = java.util.LinkedHashSet)
at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:2797)
at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:2563)
at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:2362)
at android.os.Parcel.writeList(Parcel.java:1415)
at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:2506)
at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:2362)
at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:1266)
at android.os.Parcel.writeMap(Parcel.java:1248)
at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:2476)
at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:2362)
at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:1266)
at android.os.Parcel.writeMap(Parcel.java:1248)
at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:2476)
at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:2362)
at android.os.Parcel.writeList(Parcel.java:1415)
at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:2506)
at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:2362)
at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:1298)
at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1843)
at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1389)
at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:1367)
at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:2479)
at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:2369)
at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:1298)
at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1843)
at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1389)
at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:1367)
at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:2479)
at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:2369)
at android.os.BaseBundle.dumpStats(BaseBundle.java:1917)
at android.os.BaseBundle.dumpStats(BaseBundle.java:1954)
at android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions$StopInfo.collectBundleStates(PendingTransactionActions.java:123)
at android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions$StopInfo.run(PendingTransactionActions.java:139)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1240)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:354)
at java.util.HashSet.writeObject(HashSet.java:288)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1079)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1568)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1490)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1234)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:354)
at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:2792)
at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:2563) 
at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:2362) 
at android.os.Parcel.writeList(Parcel.java:1415) 
at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:2506) 
at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:2362) 
at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:1266) 
at android.os.Parcel.writeMap(Parcel.java:1248) 
at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:2476) 
at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:2362) 
at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:1266) 
at android.os.Parcel.writeMap(Parcel.java:1248) 
at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:2476) 
at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:2362) 
at android.os.Parcel.writeList(Parcel.java:1415) 
at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:2506) 
at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:2362) 
at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:1298) 
at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1843) 
at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1389) 
at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:1367) 
at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:2479) 
at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:2369) 
at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:1298) 
at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1843) 
at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1389) 
at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:1367) 
at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:2479) 
at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:2369) 
at android.os.BaseBundle.dumpStats(BaseBundle.java:1917) 
at android.os.BaseBundle.dumpStats(BaseBundle.java:1954) 
at android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions$StopInfo.collectBundleStates(PendingTransactionActions.java:123) 
at android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions$StopInfo.run(PendingTransactionActions.java:139) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)  

Thank you in advance to help me please!
Incredible!!! I solved the problem by simply changing the data type from Set to List, evidently there is a bug in treating nested LinkedHashSets respect to a List, I would ask those responsible to investigate whether there is actually a bug or whether it is impossible to process Intents that contain data of type Set and which works with LinkedHashset behind the scenes. I hope it can help someone else avoid this problem. Thank you

I strongly recommend that you post the entire stack trace.
